# react-chartjs-2 bar touches the top

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, chartjs-2.6.0

When the data is filled it hits the top of the line. is there any option to limit the top, and I need the show the number with money symbol.

I need to change the x-axis to show more than the top limit. is there any option to it

[image: reac]

```
          <Bar
            data={incomePropertyData}
            width={100}
            height={450}
            options={{
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              legend: {
                display: true,
                fontColor: "#686868",
                fontFamily: "kanit, sans-serif",
              },
              tooltips: {
                titleAlign: "center",
                titleMarginBottom: 8,
                bodyFontFamily: "'Nunito', sans-serif",
                callbacks: {
                  label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label =
                      data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || "";
                    if (label) {
                      label += " : ";
                    }
                    label += "₹ " + tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    return label;
                  },
                },
              },
              responsive: true,
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      fontFamily: "'Nunito', sans-serif",
                      fontSize: 14,
                    },
                  },
                ],
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      fontFamily: "'Nunito', sans-serif",
                      fontSize: 14,
                      beginAtZero: true,
                      callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        return "₹ " + value;
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
            }}
          />
```

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: this is the code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try something like in the example i made here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-boilerplate-scalabw-45793890

You can use the max in the `scales: { yAxes : [{max: maxvalue}] }`

You just need to add a function which get the maximum value and add the "padding value".

i also simplified you code in my example because you got a repetition between yAxes and yAxes.

Comment: it worked. Is there any other way to set the max value with the step count? 
the y-axes count odd too.

I get 500 for each step.. is that possible to get a step count, so I can add an extra step. so it would look nice

Comment: I modified the options in the link above, let me know if it's what you wanted.
you can use the scales: `{ yAxes : [{stepSize: stepSizeValue}] }`

Comment: You should validate this answer since it fit your requirement ;)

Comment: @WilliamScalabre the link is not updated with stepsize. can please update it?
much thanks!